# glsl fragment shader rectangle wont show

Tags: java, glsl, fragment-shader

I try to draw a red rectangle on my screen, but after compiling my screen turns blue. Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? I am new to GLSL

```
#version 330

out vec4 outColor;

void drawRectangle(in vec2 pixelXY)
{
    if(pixelXY.x > 60 && pixelXY.x < 200 && pixelXY.y > 60 && pixelXY.y < 200)
    {
        outColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }
}

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0 , 0.0);
    drawRectangle(vec2(60,100));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the the funnction `drawRectangle` with constant actual paramters

```
drawRectangle(vec2(60,100));
```

Note this is the same as:

```
if (60 > 60 && 60 < 200 && 100 > 60 && 100 < 200)
{
    outColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

To solve the issue you have to change the actual parameter to the window coordinates of the fragment which is currently processed. See [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml):

```
drawRectangle( gl_FragCoord.xy );
```

Note, the [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader) is executed once for each fragment and the built-in uniform variable [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) contains the coordinates of the current fragment.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation! it solved my problem and now I understand better how fragment shaders work